# Почему к методу Array обращаются через его прототип?

Tags: javascript

Заинтересовало меня это потому, что вижу не в первый раз. Сам не уверен в правильности понимания и решил спросить, почему и для чего пишут вот так:

```
function method(object){
    var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот кусок когда преобразует объект в обычный Array, чтобы для arguments можно было использовать функции прототипа или чтобы функции, принимающие только Array, могли нормально работать. Конкретно эта строчка отбрасывает первый аргумент. Видимо, дальше написано что-то вроде:

```
 myfunct.apply(this,arguments);
```

Иногда еще пишут

```
 [].splice.call(arguments,0);
```

Это короче, но в таком случае один раз создается лишний объект типа массива, поэтому в циклах лучше использовать Array.prototype.method.call

Методы splice и slice возвращают новый Array, поэтому это часто используется еще и для неглубокого клонирования Array:

```
var newArray=oldarray.slice();
```

Вот что пишут об этом в [спецификации](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.4.html#x15.4.4.10):

> ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ Функция slice является нарочито родовой функцией. Она не требует, чтобы её значение this было объектом Array. Поэтому она может передаваться другим типам объектов для использования в качестве метода. Возможность успешного применения функции slice к объекту среды зависит от реализации.

Comment: @vas, прочитайте спецификацию, хотя-бы на русском, от начала до конца, она короткая и даже вполне понятная (особенно с аннотациями), и многое станет понятно.

Comment: Этот код выдернут из миксин -  

    function extend(object){
 var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
 length    = array.length,
 item;

 for(var i = 0; i < length; ++i){
  item = array[i];
  for(var prop in item){
   if(typeof object.prototype[prop] === 'undefined'){
    object.prototype[prop] = item[prop];
   }
  }
 }
}

Comment: нелучший надо сказать код, почему-бы просто не перебирать с 1 а не 0, если уж перебираем по длине, потом prop in item... видимо это расширяет объект списком свойств/методов... не перекрывая его (правда непонятно, почему перекрывают если значение prototype - undefined, мне кажется, это баг).

Comment: Я его немного изменил... Вот отсюда взял: http://habrahabr.ru/post/132340/

Comment: @eicto, вообще-то, вы сами дали ответ на другой вопрос, еще и толком не разбираясь.

Дело в следующем (то, что имели в виду вы).

Если мы, к примеру, объявим функцию

fn(){return arguments;}

и проверим, является ли возвращаемое значение массивом

fn("asd","asd","asd") instanceof Array;

результат будет, увы, false.

Дак вот, получается, что к возвращаемому значению мы не можем применить методы массива - логично же.
И чтобы таковое было возможно, реализовали через Array.prototype.slice.apply(fn("asd","asd","ASD"));

А в ECMAScript5 можно просто arguments.slice();

Comment: @smackmychi, я об этом и написал.

В [es5](http://es5.github.io/#x10.6) нет никакого arguments.slice();

    > (function(){console.log(arguments.slice);})();

    undefined

как, впрочем, и в es6.

Comment: В случае же автора - дело в том, что при вызове Array.prototype.<функция> - будет вызван метод не конкретного массива, а объекта-массива (чем и является по сути Array.prototype). И под единичный экземпляр памяти выделено не будет. Это как статические методы класса в Java.
_____

Ни о какой правильности понимания в вашем случае речи не идет, увы.

Comment: @smackmychi, не пойму, в чем претензия, вы не прочитали вопрос, спеку не знаете, обманываете про её содержание и говорите мне, что я чего-то не понял? Давайте проще: методы call и apply просто подменяют контекст у функции, таким образом контекст метода, записанного в прототип, становится равным первому аргументу метода call прототипа Function. А так как функции типа slice не требуют, чтобы аргумент был инстансом Array, это позволяет нам превратить в Array любой объект, у которого есть целые ключи и свойство length.

Comment: Здорово, потому что в последний момент отказались добавлять эту фичу. А я надеялся, проблем не будет

https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es5-discuss/2009-August/003112.html

Answer (score 2):

Если коротко, то это для более уверенного преобразования объектов в тип Array. Или преобразования Object в Array.

Если у вас на вход прилетит такой объект

```
var my_object = {
    '0': 'zero',
    '1': 'one',
    '2': 'two',
    '3': 'three',
    '4': 'four',
    length: 5
};
```

то данная функция его преобразует в массив, потому что все атрибуты массива присутствуют. А если использовать `my_object.slice()`, то браузер может ругнуться.

Если глубже, то когда вы создаёте объект так:

```
`my_object1 = {}`
```

то у него родительский прототип Object

А если так:

```
 my_object1 = []
```

то Array.

А что бы превратить вручную Object в Array, используют вашу конструкцию.

Вот как-то так.

Answer (score -1):

Как-то так

> prototype
>
> Прототип объекта
>
> Описание, примеры
>
> Все объекты в javascript наследуют от
> Object, и потому имеют свойство
> prototype.
>
> Как правило, свойство prototype
> используется для предоставления
> базового набора функциональных
> возможностей классу объектов. Новые
> экземпляры объекта "наследуют"
> поведение прототипа, присвоенного
> этому объекту.
>
> Предположим, что нам требуется
> добавить в объект Array метод, который
> возвращает значение наибольшего
> элемента массива. Для этого
> объявляется функция, которая
> добавляется к объекту Array.prototype,
> а затем используется.

[Отсюда](http://javascript.ru/Object/prototype)

Comment: Не понимаю :) Если я меняю НАТИВНЫЙ метод через прототип, то где бы я не вызывал метод, который изменил, он везде будет измененный?

Comment: @vas, это не правильный ответ на ваш вопрос :) Это просто описание, зачем prototype.

Comment: @eicto, вопрос был "Почему к методу Array обращаются через его прототип?" facepalm.

Comment: Спасибо Всем! Не один ваш ответ не являлся для меня исчерпывающим, но ваши споры к этому привели! Поэтому ещё раз - Спасибо, и можете продолжать спорить, возможно, я ещё что-то узнаю.

Comment: Ну а тело вопроса не надо читать? 

> почему и для чего пишут вот так:

В любом случае какое отношение имеет ваш ответ к даже такой постановке вопроса? Если бы прямо на такое отвечать, то "потому-что объект Array.prototype имеет этот метод, а объект Array - нет" (хотя вот в FF он есть, не уверен, почему делает как раз то же самое, что call, в спеках этого нет, в v8 (на ноде по крайней мере) это не реализовано)